# when i run flutter app it automatical terminated

Tags: flutter, runtime-error, flutter-dependencies

/C:/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:2181:41: Error: Type 'MultiChildLayoutParentData' not found.
class LayoutId extends ParentDataWidget {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:2268:9: Error: Type 'MultiChildLayoutDelegate' not found.
final MultiChildLayoutDelegate delegate;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:2271:3: Error: Type 'RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox' not found.
RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {

when iam try to run demo app or any my project of flitter in visual studio code the program will terminated and show below error meesage

/C:/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:2181:41: Error: Type 'MultiChildLayoutParentData' not found.
class LayoutId extends ParentDataWidget {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:2268:9: Error: Type 'MultiChildLayoutDelegate' not found.
final MultiChildLayoutDelegate delegate;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:2271:3: Error: Type 'RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox' not found.
RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {

Comment: try  run flutter `pub cache clean` in terminal at project directory

Comment: We can't do anything for you without the code you used. My first totally random guess is that you didn't use a Scaffold widget.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.